# Is there any Potterverse explanation for a wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

Is there a reason in the Potterverse to use a wand?

There are many creatures that use magic without a wand, why do wizards need to use wands?

Comment: It's essentially a focus point for magic when casting the majority of spells, though not all of them (Apparition, for example). House Elves do a similar thing with pointing their fingers when casting spells. I'm not sure if there are any decent book quotes to go along with that, though; I certainly can't think of any right now.

Comment: Oh, one other point that just occurred to me, one of the major points of contention between wizards and other races (House Elves, I believe goblins too, likely others) is the laws passed that prohibit possessing a wand; that sort of indicates that a wand is the best way to channel magic - House Elves can point and cast a spell, but it might be a lot more effective if they were using a wand.

Answer (score 13):

Wands are a way to channel (or focus) your magic. As Ollivander tells Harry in HP7:

> Oh yes, if you are any wizard at all you will be able to channel
>   your magic through almost any instrument.

In addition, a properly affiliated wand reinforces your magic in a sort-of feedback loop, see that same explanation from Ollivander in terms of wandlore.

---

Other creatures' magic is different from Wizards, perhaps it's easier to channel/focus; or perhaps they are restricted to magic types that are wandless (JKR never expanded on that).

But wands do seem to offer even non-humans better magic scope, as evidenced by Griphook's explanation to Harry, again in Deathly Hallows:

> “The right to carry a wand,” said the goblin quietly, “has long
>   been contested between wizards and goblins.”
>   “Well, goblins can do magic without wands,” said Ron.
>   “That is immaterial! Wizards refuse to share the secrets of
>   wandlore with other magical beings, **they deny us the possibility
>   of extending our powers**!”

Comment: Could a wizard learn to use their magic without a wand, given that children with the "magic gene" can perform "instinctive magic?"

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - yes. There was magic done without wands before they started to make them. I can scare up a quote if you ask as a question

Comment: I have asked this question before (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103838/why-does-a-wizard-need-a-wand-to-perform-magic) but it was marked as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2):

## Wands are used to channel magic and make it more focused.

In his notes for “Babbitty Rabbitty and Her Cackling Stump”, Dumbledore describes wands as instruments through which magic is supposed to be channeled.

> “While the “rogue” ability to perform magic sometimes appears in those of apparent non-magical descent (though several later studies have suggested that there will have been a witch or wizard somewhere on the family tree), Muggles cannot perform magic. The best — or worst — they could hope for are random and uncontrollable effects generated by a genuine magical wand, which, as an instrument through which magic is supposed to be channeled, sometimes holds residual power, which it may discharge at odd moments — see also the notes on wandlore for “The Tale of the Three Brothers.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

While wizards are capable of doing magic without a wand just as non-humans are, the results of it would be less precise and less powerful than that of magic done by using a wand.

> The magic wand originated in Europe. Wands channel magic so as to make its effects both more precise and more powerful, although it is generally held to be a mark of the very greatest witches and wizards that they have also been able to produce wandless magic of a very high quality. As the Native American Animagi and potion-makers demonstrated, wandless magic can attain great complexity, but Charms and Transfiguration are very difficult without one. 
> <sub><sup>*[- History of Magic in North America, Fourteenth Century – Seventeenth Century (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en)*</sup></sub>

Wands focus and channel magic, improving its effect. Non-human creatures don’t *need* wands to use magic, but it’s likely that they too would use wands if wizards hadn’t outlawed it, since goblins in general are very angry with wizards for not allowing them to have wands.

Answer (score 0):

It is noteworthy that wizards don't **need** to use a wand. According to Pottermore, wands are a European invention, African wizards in particular regularly perform wandless magic; as did native American wizards.