# Can a Wizard control his magical powers without a wand?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, wandlore

In the Potterverse, it is seen that some children are born with the "magic gene" and others are not (e.g. Lily Potter and her non-magic sister Petunia). Those children from the United Kingdom who possess magic will be enrolled at Hogwarts where they will learn, amongst other things, how to use their gifts properly. We learn early on that a wizard needs a wand, and in the Philosopher's Stone film we see Harry visiting Olivander's to acquire his wand.

[This Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46532/is-there-any-potterverse-explanation-for-a-wand)'s answer sufficiently describes why Wizards use a wand.

But we know Wizard children can perform magic by instinct without ever getting a wand or learning how to  control their magical powers.

My question is, Could a wizard, with enough training, become able to control his or her magic without one?

Comment: Squibs are Muggles born to magical parents. Petunia and Lily's parents were Muggles. Hence, Petunia is not a Squib.

Comment: Corrected, thanks :-)

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Hi Maguire, I have edited your Question as per your discussion with DVK [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/46536/54887) and nominated it for reopening. If you believe I have crossed a line here, you can rollback (And of course I'd withdraw my vote because then it again becomes duplicate)

Comment: In any case, in the movies at least we have seen Dumbledore and Moody doing Wandless magic quite impressively so I believe it is possible. Not so sure about the books though, Things get muddled between the two for me.